Not able to get streaming audio input from streaming server in DialogFlow CX
I have created a application that taked UDP audio from Asterisk sent using ARI-bridge and it pipes through Dialogflow CX. Application is build in NodeJS technology
Initially while running the code, first create stream using dialogFlow cx config (like projectId, agentId etc.)
let audioDataStream = rtpServer.createStream(payload.port);
dialogflowConnector.start(audioDataStream);

The above called start method is as follows
start(stream) {
    //pipe the audio through!
    this._asteriskAudioStream = stream;
    stream.inRStream.on('data', (audio) => {
        this._receivedAudioMessage(audio);
    });
}
_receivedAudioMessage(audio) {
    if (dialogFlowStream && dialogFlowStream.writable) {
        try {
            dialogFlowStream.write({ inputAudio: audio });
        } catch (err) {
            //because dialogflow can be shit and say its writeable but its not
        }
    }
}

Now, to create stream below are the parts of code
const { PassThrough, Duplex } = require('stream');
class DuplexThrough {
    constructor() {
        this.inRStream = new PassThrough();
        this.outWStream = new PassThrough();
    }

    end() {
        this.inRStream.end();
        this.outWStream.end();
    }
}
createStream(port) {

        const stream = new DuplexThrough();

        this.log.info({ port }, 'Creating a new stream based on source port');

        stream.inRStream.on('close', () => {
            // not sure if this is actually working yet
            this.log.info({ port }, 'removing event listener for data on port as stream finished');
            this.removeAllListeners(`data-${port}`);
        });

        this.log.info(`listening on data-${port} for data`);

        this.once(`data-${port}`, (audio, rinfo) => {
            this.log.info(`Audio Stream started from port ${port}`);

            stream.outWStream.on('data', (audioData) => {
                //this.log.info('sending audio back to asterisk', audioData.length, rinfo.port, rinfo.address);
                this.socket.send(audioData, rinfo.port, rinfo.address);
            });
        });

        this.on(`data-${port}`, (data) => {
            stream.inRStream.write(data);
        });

        this.streams.set(port, stream);

        return stream;
    }

The main issue is while making a call to voice bot the audio stream is not getting read and I'm not able to get any response from the bot.
I tried applying the code available at @google-cloud/dialogflow-cx the npm package which I have used to integrate dialogFlow cx.
Also tried with static test audio.raw file but not getting any response.
